# wp_update_post function exclude specific field

Tags: database, post-meta, updates

I am using a function to update the default post and this function updates the language post publish date and some fields. it's working fine but the problem is that our meta_post field "_mydomain" also updates value like the default post. is it possible I only exclude this meta_post field? i don't want to change this value from this function

```
foreach (array_slice($languages, 1) as $language) {
$updatess = array( 'ID' => $language, 'post_date' => $timeD, 'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $timeD ) );
wp_update_post( $updatess );
if(!empty($version)){
update_field( 'version', $version , $language );    
}       
        
  }
```